# Restore state of toggle button on canceling dialog

Tags: android, android-togglebutton, switchcompat

I have a toggle button in my activity. When switch is On, it shows enable dialog and switch is Off, it shows disable dialog.

```
((SwitchCompat) findViewById(R.id.toggleButton)).setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if(isChecked){
                ((StyleableTextView) findViewById(R.id.lbl_toggle_status)).setText("on");
                showEnableSharingDialog();
            } else {
                ((StyleableTextView) findViewById(R.id.lbl_toggle_status)).setText("off");
                showDiasableShareingDialog();
            }
        }
    });
```

This is enable dialog:

```
private void showEnableShareingDialog() {
    final CharSequence options[]= getResources().getStringArray(R.array.sharing_options);
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(SettingsActivity.this);

     builder.setTitle(getString(R.string.you_want_to_enable_prev_sigtings));

    builder.setItems(options, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            if(which==0){
                mShareSigtings=true;
                mEnableShareing=true;
                updateSettings();
            } else if(which==1){
                mShareSigtings=true;
                mEnableShareing=false;
                updateSettings();
            } else {
                /*---todo---*/
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        }
    });
    builder.show();
}
```

This is disable dialog:

```
private void showDiasableShareingDialog() {
    final CharSequence options[]= getResources().getStringArray(R.array.remove_sharing_options);
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(SettingsActivity.this);

    builder.setTitle(getString(R.string.you_want_to_remove_prev_sigtings));

    builder.setItems(options, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            if (which == 0) {
                mShareSigtings = false;
                mRemovePrevSigtings = true;
                updateSettings();
            } else if (which == 1) {
                mShareSigtings = false;
                mRemovePrevSigtings = false;
                updateSettings();
            } else {
                /*---todo---*/
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        }
    });
    builder.show();
}
```

In both dialogs, toggle button switches it state i.e, say toggle was in ON state then I press the button, dialog pops up, when i press CANCEL it goes from ON to OFF state. Expected result was when CANCEL is pressed, toggle button should remain on its original position i.e, if toggle is ON then on pressing CANCEL it should remain ON. How am I going to achieve this kind of operation?

Also, if i do something like below both the dialogs continuously pops up on pressing CANCEL.

```
if(((SwitchCompat)findViewById(R.id.toggle3)).isChecked()){
                    ((SwitchCompat)findViewById(R.id.toggle3)).setChecked(false);
}else {
                    ((SwitchCompat)findViewById(R.id.toggle3)).setChecked(true);
}
```

Comment: Your condition for setOnChangeListener is causing the problem when you set the switch toggle. It gets triggered when the code for programatically toggling the switch via .setChecked gets called.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to know that:

- onCheckedChanged is invoked AFTER the status change of the SwichCompat.
- if you added a OnCheckedChangeListener to your SwitchCompat, this listener will be triggered after any change of the status of the swich (by code or by manually pressing)

So, a fast fix for this, before you change the check status of the swich set null as onCheckedChanged then put the listener again. Here is an example:

```
 SwitchCompat mySwich = ((SwitchCompat) findViewById(R.id.toggleButton))   
     OnCheckedChangeListener listener = new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                    if(isChecked){
                        ((StyleableTextView) findViewById(R.id.lbl_toggle_status)).setText("on");
                        showEnableSharingDialog();
                    } else {
                        ((StyleableTextView) findViewById(R.id.lbl_toggle_status)).setText("off");
                        showDiasableShareingDialog();
                    }
                }
            };
mySwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(listener);
```

And on your CANCEL callback, you can do something like that:

```
mySwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null);
if(((SwitchCompat)findViewById(R.id.toggle3)).isChecked()){
                    ((SwitchCompat)findViewById(R.id.toggle3)).setChecked(false);
}else {
                    ((SwitchCompat)findViewById(R.id.toggle3)).setChecked(true);
}
mySwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(listener);
```

Comment: thanks for the help doing like this solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

```html
else {
   /*---todo---*/
   dialog.cancel();
}
```

on each of those else code above signifying the cancel action which falls on "else" for your case - you could add the

```
((SwitchCompat)findViewById(R.id.toggle3)).setChecked(false);
```

or

```
((SwitchCompat)findViewById(R.id.toggle3)).setChecked(true);
```

below the /*---todo---*/ comment and just right before you dialog.cancel();

Comment: do i have to add it for both dialogs or any one of them?

Comment: @Raj try on one or both.

Comment: i tried as you said, turns out it fails in one of the conditions depending upon where you put it also dialog shows two times